# What is the english for "Toute proportion gardée"?

Tags: traduction

I hope the question is self explanatory.

I'm seeking for the idiomatic English equivalent.

Comment: When asking a translation question, I think it is better to go on the target language board, in that case: [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: We can help you with formulating an idea in French or with understanding a French sentence, but not with idiomatic English. I suggest reposting on [english.se]. Be sure to explain in English what the phrase means, as most users there don't speak French.  See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62814/expression-saving-on-the-parrots-chocolate-is-futile) for a similar example. An example sentence (in English, of course, with the equivalent of *toutes proportions gardées* missing) might also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. It can be “proportionally”, “up to a point” or “to some extent”.

Answer (score 1):

An unwieldy translation would be "making the necessary adjustments".  The idea is that in a comparison there are some differences in the comparands, but if you allow for those differences then the comparands may be seen to be similar.

If you're in a formal context it would be better to use the latin phrase: *mutatis mutandis*

Comment: +1 for _mutatis mutandis_

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you may use "all things considered" which, arguably, is often used as "toutes proportions gardées" when about quantities, as in this example:

> Actually, Fitch thinks his family is doing fine right now, all things considered.

Example from [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+things+considered).